# Could it possible to find out who changed sitecore password through sitecore logs or db?

Tags: security

Is it possible find out who changed sitecore password through sitecore logs or db ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not after-the-fact. I just tried logging into a vanilla Sitecore 8.2u2 instance as admin and changed the password. The only AUDIT message in the logs (where you would normally expect these events to be registered) was this one.

> 14264 15:41:03 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Login

It is possible that if you installed something like the [Advanced System Reporter](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/A/Advanced_System_Reporter.aspx), you would be able to get more detailed information on what your users were up to. But this would not apply retroactively on what has already transpired.

I would take the issue to Sitecore Support; I feel a change password event is worthy of an AUDIT log entry out of the box.

Comment: Keep us posted with response from Sitecore , if any configuration parameter enables this logging