# Item with children got deleted from master database

Tags: content-management

One item with its children got deleted from the master database on my production environment. after installing the backup databases I found that the item was last presented on the 19th June and I'm trying to find out how it got deleted. I checked history table,PublishQueue table and WorkFlow History table and found nothing.

The last operation on that item was done on 14th June with the Saving Event. I also tried reviewing logs in between the time but didn't find anything related to that Item Id.

Is there anything I can try to find out the cause of deletion of that item?

Comment: Any package installed? Anything in `sitecore_master.dbo.History` sql table?

Comment: Not after the fact, no. If you didn't explicitly have logging in place already. Use workflows and permissions to control, what users delete and so on. See also https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/could-it-possible-to-find-out-who-changed-sitecore-password-through-sitecore-log/3823#3823

Comment: Also, did you check the recycle bin?

Comment: Yes, I checked recycle bin.

Comment: @MarekMusielak Nothing was there in sitecore_master.dbo.History table related to Delete Event.

Comment: Maybe the item was moved? Have you tried to search by id?

Comment: Item deletions do not go throw workflow either, there is no "soft delete" option so that will not help (permissions will though). OOTB, Sitecore *will* log the fact an item has been deleted/recycled when a user deletes an item from the Content Editor. Note that only the actual item that is deleted is logged, maybe a parent item was deleted and that's why the guid you are looking for was not found in the log (i.e. it was a child item itself).

Answer (score 1):

#### No

Short answer is no. If it's not in your log files, there is nowhere else you could look. It would get logged to the regular logfiles, and it should probaly show up in your History tables.

All of this is difficult to fix AFTER it has happened however.

Your situation and the answer is the same, as given here: [Could it possible to find out who changed sitecore password through sitecore logs or db?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/could-it-possible-to-find-out-who-changed-sitecore-password-through-sitecore-log/3823#3823)